# Capturing the Windows Shutdown Screen

Tags: windows, display, shutdown, capture

Is it possible to capture or extract from the system files the shutdown screen windows xp displays when shutting down?  I think that would involve something that still remain active when Windows is going down and is still able to write to the hdd.

Comment: do you really like it so much ?.. . kidding follow bryans' advice

Comment: [find it here](http://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https://mysite.uchicago.edu/personal/bsdad_rcarter/Blog/Lists/Photos/112107_1514_ParallelsDe1.png&imgrefurl=https://mysite.uchicago.edu/personal/bsdad_rcarter/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx%3FID%3D12&usg=__Uu3QiNqnDLEgClIv7QTrFwukp64=&h=302&w=404&sz=27&hl=en&start=17&sig2=rAn9bLiOCQBLS_Na_W3tYA&zoom=1&tbnid=sY53JbbMTLo93M:&tbnh=93&tbnw=124&ei=q2WUTcLIO8G1tgeF29SKDA&prev=/images%3Fq%3Dwindows%2Bxp%2Bshutting%2Bdown%26um%3D1%26hl%3Den%26safe%3Dactive%26sa%3DN%26biw%3D1366%26bih%3D679%26tbs%3Disch:1&um=1&itbs=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run Windows XP in a Virtual Machine and capture the shutdown screen using tools on the host PC?